# ag-grid Cannot read property 'setRowData' because gridOptions.api undefined

Tags: ag-grid

i have a ag-grid working in project. but now when i ported the same to another page i got some error .. i tried to avoid the http call in between and directly tried to set the ROW Data through

```
 $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(RowDatas);
```

but error is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRowData' of undefined"

So n debug i realised api is Undefined . here is my complete code . please check what i missed ..

```
<head>
<script src="js/angular_1_3_8.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-filter.js"></script>
<script src="workbench/agGrid/dist/ag-grid.js?ignore=notused34"></script>
<script>
    agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);
    var app = angular.module("workbenchApp", ['angular.filter',"agGrid"]);
    app.controller("workBenchCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $filter) {

    var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Name", field: "Name"},
    {headerName: "Cr", field: "dc"},
    {headerName: "Ac", field: "da"},
    {headerName: "Mo", field: "dm"},

];

var RowDatas=[{"Name": "SUHDLOG.DAT", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2002-12-27 00:00:00", "dm": "2002-12-27 09:51:22"},
{ "Name": "BOOTLOG.PRV", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2005-04-01 00:00:00", "dm": "2005-04-01 15:13:30"},
{ "Name": "FRUNLOG.TXT", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2002-12-27 00:00:00", "dm": "2002-12-27 09:52:56"},
{ "Name": "COMMAND.COM", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2002-12-27 00:00:00", "dm": "1999-04-23 22:22:00"},
{ "Name": "BOOTLOG.TXT", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2005-04-02 00:00:00", "dm": "2005-04-02 14:38:00"},
{ "Name": "DETLOG.TXT", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2002-12-28 00:00:00", "dm": "2002-12-28 09:56:02"},
{ "Name": "CONFIG.SYS", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2005-06-16 00:00:00", "dm": "2003-07-03 18:39:50"},
{ "Name": "DBLSPACE.BIN", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2002-12-27 00:00:00", "dm": "1999-04-23 22:22:00"},
{ "Name": "MSDOS.SYS", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2003-07-03 00:00:00", "dm": "2002-12-27 10:01:58"},
{ "Name": "DRVSPACE.BIN", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2002-12-27 00:00:00", "dm": "1999-04-23 22:22:00"},
{ "Name": "MSDOS.---", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2002-12-27 00:00:00", "dm": "2002-12-27 09:46:28"},
{ "Name": "SETUPLOG.TXT", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2002-12-27 00:00:00", "dm": "2002-12-27 10:04:12"},
{ "Name": "WSOCK32.DLL", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2005-06-16 00:00:00", "dm": "2002-12-27 09:47:10"},
{ "Name": "CFGWIZ.DLL", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2005-02-26 00:00:00", "dm": "2002-12-27 09:47:12"},
];

$scope.gridOptions = {
        angularCompileHeaders: true,
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        rowData:[{"Name": "SUHDLOG.DAT", "dc": "1970-01-01 05:30:00", "da": "2002-12-27 00:00:00", "dm": "2002-12-27 09:51:22"}]
                };

    /*
    $http.get('FileList.json').success(function (response) {
    $scope.TData = response;
    DateArray=$scope.TData.Files;
    $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(DateArray);


    });
    */
    $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(RowDatas);

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="workbenchApp">
    <div ng-controller="workBenchCtrl">
        <div ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-blue" style="height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grid api will only be ready once the grid has initialized. You can use the gridReady event for this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    onGridReady: function() {
        $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(...your data);
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Had the same problem that seemed to be caused by the method being called twice.  The first time before the api was defined, making the inner code would crash.  On the second pass, the api was defined.

OnGridReady did not work for me, neither did using vue's nextTick or timeout.

finally resolved it by using an if:

```
if (this.gridOptions.api) {
    this.gridOptions.api.setFilterModel(null);
}
```

This allowed it to pass over it the first time and not crash, then catch it the second time and do the work.

(Hope this helps someone.  Caused me a good deal of frustration.)

Answer (score 2):

If the type of the ag grid row model being used is not client-side then remove the **rowData** property on the grid. This way you will not get an error and params.api will not be undefined on **onGridReady**.

setRowData is defined only on client side row model.

getRows function will handle setting the server side data within the table.

Reference for server side row model (example)-

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/server-side-operations-nodejs/

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 onGridReady: function(params) {
            params.api.setRowData(...your data);
        }
```